# How to forbid the opening of the dialog box when clicking on a file input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, input, jquery-events

I'm working on a little project and I have to cancel the event that normally happens when clicking on a file input : the display of a dialog box which allows the user to choose a file.

Here is my file input :

```
<input id="echangevignette" type="file">
```

I didn't find anything concerning cancelling this kind of events so that's why I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

Good old `Event.preventDefault()` should do the trick for you:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { 
                document.getElementById('echangevignette').onclick = e => e.preventDefault();
            });
        </script>
        <input id="echangevignette" type="file">
    </body>
</html>
```

P.S. You can skip the `DOMContentLoaded` event listener if you load your scripts after the `<input id="echangevignette" type="file">`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick....

HTML

```
<input id="echangevignette" type="file">
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("echangevignette").addEventListener("click", function(event){
 event.preventDefault()
});
```